# SQL error: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, php

I have following very simple PHP MySQL Query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bundesland WHERE bkuerzel = ' . $_GET['q'];
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

When I execute the query with a click on a item with the value "Wien" on a dropdown menu I get "SQL error:Unknown column 'Wien' in 'where clause' in", but as you can see in the picture below I have the column.

[image: Picture of my database table]

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with your question, but please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1324019

Comment: You have a problem with wrapping quote marks around the predicate.  Solving your SQL injection attack problems will also solve this quote-wrapping problem.

Comment: Also, you should read the opening warning at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `$_GET['q']`, which must be `Wien`, should be in quotes

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bundesland WHERE bkuerzel = '" . $_GET['q'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Without putting quotes around `$_GET['q']`, mysqld thinks the value of `$_GET['q']` is a field.